# Dimension of the graph of a product of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $f,g\in{\mathcal C}[0,1]$ (continuous real-valued funtions defined on $[0,1]$).

What can be said about the (Hausdorff or box-counting) dimension of the graph of $f\cdot g$ in terms of the dimensions of the graphs of $f$ and $g$?

In particular, what can be said about the dimension of the graph of $f^2$ in terms of the dimension of the graph of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the second question. Let $I(f)$ and $I(f^2)$ be the graphs of $f$ and $f^2$. For $n\in\mathbb Z$, let $A_n:=f^{-1}([2^n,2^{n+1}))$, $B_n:=f^{-1}((-2^{n+1},-2^n])$ and $C:=f^{-1}(0)$. It is easy to show that the map $(x,f(x))\mapsto (x,f^2(x))$ is bi-Lipschitz on each of the sets $A_n$, $B_n$ and $C$. So the Hausdorff dimension of $I(f)\cap (A_n\times \mathbb R)$ is equal to the Hausdorff dimension of $I(f^2)\cap (A_n\times \mathbb R)$, etc. It follows that $I(f)$ and $I(f^2)$ have the same Hausdorff dimension.

I don't know if this is true for the Minkowski dimension or not.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I'm not an expert in Hausdorff dimension.

Additionally, It seeems that you are thinking in functions with domain the whole real line, but I'm only interested in continuous functions from $[0,1]$. I don't know if this is a key fact or not.

Comment: Can you give me a reference for what you said? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Behaviour_under_unions_and_products. Also, it is easy to see that a bi-Lipschitz map does not change the Hausdorff dimension. You can verify this by using the direct definition of Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: If i understand it right, it think  this laso works for $f^n$ for any  positive integer $n$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Yes, the same proof works.